# Given a pointer to member a within a struct, write a routine that returns a pointer to the struct

Tags: c, struct

Here is an interview question that I saw on some forum.  I've been trying to figure out how it works but I don't quite get it.  Could somebody explain how it works?

Q: Given a pointer to member a within a struct, write a routine that returns a pointer to the struct.

```
struct s 
{
   ...
   int a;
   …
};

struct s *get_s_ptr(int *a_ptr)
{
   // implement this.
}
```

The answer is:

```
struct s* get_s_ptr(int *a_ptr)
{
   return (struct s*)((char*)a_ptr - (int)&((struct s*)0)->a);
}
```

Comment: What **are** you asking?

Comment: Sorry, I had the question in the title but not the post itself. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How does it work?

The fundamental equation here (all arithmetic in bytes) is

```
address of struct member s->a == s + byte offset of a
```

Given the type of `s`, a single compiler, and a single target machine, they determined the byte offset of `a`—it's the same for every struct of type s.

You're given the left-hand side and your interviewer asked you to recover `s`.  You can do this by getting a new equation; subtract the byte offset from both sides:

```
address of struct member s->a - byte offset of a == s
```

In the problem, you're *given* the address of `s->a`, but you have to figure out the byte offset.  To do this you use the original equation *again* with `s` set to zero:

```
address of struct member s->a where s is zero == zero + byte offset of a 
                                              == byte offset of a
```

The left-hand side in C is built as follows

```
struct pointer s where s is zero                            (struct s *)0
struct member s->a where s is zero                          ((struct s*)0)->a
address of s->a where s is zero                             &((struct s*)0)->a
```

Final steps:

1. To make the arithmetic legal C this byte offset is cast to an integer.
2. To make sure the subtraction is done in units of bytes, `a_ptr` is cast to `char *`.
3. To give the result the right type the difference is cast to `struct s *`.

---

Addendum: As Eli Bendersky points out, you should try to avoid situations where this code would be necessary.  There is almost always a better way.

Comment: you gave a nicely detailed explanation of an utterly wrong, non-standard and generally *bad* piece of code.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is: it doesn't. It doesn't work, even if it might seem to "work" at the first sight. The "answer" makes an attempt to dereference a null pointer, which leads to undefined behavior. So, unless your idea of "working" includes undefined behavior, that answer does not work.

There are more problems with that solution, besides the attempt to derefercence a null pointer (although that alone is perfectly enough to throw that "answer" to garbage bin). Another problem is that the result of `(struct s*) 0` is a null pointer of `struct s *` type. The language makes no guarantees about the actual physical value of a null pointer. If could easily be something like `0xBAADFOOD`, which would immediately screw up the intended functionality of the "answer".

The proper implementation of the implied technique would involve the standard `offsetof` macro (already suggested in Nyan's answer, but I'll repeat it one more time)

```
struct s* get_s_ptr(int *a_ptr)
{
   return (struct s*) ((char *) a_ptr - offsetof(struct s, a));
}
```

Comment: Agree about 'NULL' pointer. Theoretically it might be non-zero, this screws things.
However there's NO dereferencing of this pointer. If you look at the definition of 'offsetof' - you'll see exactly the same thing.

That is, writing &(pObj->a) does NOT dereference anything. Because the result of the expression is the address. It's just an arithmetics

Comment: &(pObj->a) is same as &( (*pObj).a). So it's dereferencing NULL pointer if pObj is NULL.

Comment: I tried it here: http://codepad.org/PtLv8XN7 . ((struct s*)0)->a leads to a seg fault while &((struct s*)0)->a leads to the correct offset. Any thoughts?  Regardless, offsetof() is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: @valdo: What `offsetof` is doing internally is none of our business. `offsetof` is a standard library component. It is only C in terms of interface, while its implementation is not C and/or not required to be C. In other words, in your C code you might not be allowed to do what if perfectly acceptable for `offsetof`. And there is a dereference of a null pointer there. Operator `->` is a dereference.

Comment: @Mike: The results of your trials mean nothing more than just that there is some platform on which it "works". This, of course, does not make it a legal solution in C.

Answer (score 4):

You can use offsetof macro.

```
struct s* get_s_ptr(int *a_ptr)
{
   return (struct s*)((char*)a_ptr - offsetof(struct s,a) );
}
```

I's late. my internet connection's slow.

Answer (score 1):

Thought this would be helpful,

```
/* offsetof example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct mystruct {
    char singlechar;
    char arraymember[10];
    char anotherchar;
};

int main ()
{
    printf ("offsetof(mystruct,singlechar) is %d\n",offsetof(mystruct,singlechar));
    printf ("offsetof(mystruct,arraymember) is %d\n",offsetof(mystruct,arraymember));
    printf ("offsetof(mystruct,anotherchar) is %d\n",offsetof(mystruct,anotherchar));

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
offsetof(mystruct,singlechar) is 0
offsetof(mystruct,arraymember) is 1
offsetof(mystruct,anotherchar) is 11
```

So in your case,

```
return (struct s*) ((char *) a_ptr - offsetof(struct s, a));
```

- cast `aptr` to char*
- subtract the offset of `a` wrt to `struct s`
- cast to `struct s*`
- return the `resultant ptr`